# Twitter API undefined PHP index

Tags: php, undefined-index

I am using [this Twitter API code](https://github.com/kmaida/twitter-timeline-php/blob/master/_includes/twitter.php) to display tweets on my website. Currently I am getting "undefined index" PHP errors, which do not affect functionality but I would like to know the correct way to resolve them anyway. I am guessing I need to check if a response from the Twitter API exists first, before defining the variable, but not sure the correct way to go about that.

Here's a sample of the code:

```
$id = $tweet['id'];
$formattedTweet = !$isRetweet ? formatTweet($tweet['full_text']) : formatTweet($retweet['full_text']);
$statusURL = 'http://twitter.com/' . $userScreenName . '/status/' . $id;
$date = timeAgo($tweet['created_at']);
$mediaURL = $tweet['entities']['media'][0]['media_url_https'];
```

Let's say, for example, that a returned tweet does not have an image, I will then get the error `Notice: Undefined index: media in ...` from the $mediaURL variable. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check, example:

```
$mediaURL = '';
if( isset($tweet['entities']['media'][0]['media_url_https']) ){
   $mediaURL = $tweet['entities']['media'][0]['media_url_https'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `var_dump($tweet)` to see what does `$tweet` contains. The error means that there is no such key as `media`  in the `$tweet['entities']` array (assuming `$tweet` and `$tweet['media']` are both array  based on the way you have presented) . After that you can use `isset` function or Null coalescing operator to check if the key that you are looking for exists or not then take necessary action.

e.g.

```
$mediaUrl = $tweet['entities']['media'][0]['media_url_https'] ?? '';
```